# delete from a table where the id is auto incremented in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php

I am trying to perform a delete action, but in my where clause am using an ID field that is auto incremented.how do i state it in my where clause?

Comment: please clarify your question ! you can use `delete from tablename where ID=? ` . may your question is You dont want to make a gap between rows in auto increment id field.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the inserted ID to perform the delete. For example, using prepared statemenst in PHP:

If we want to insert a row in this table
 table_name [ id (AUTOINCREMENT), field_1 (INTEGER) ]

```
// Execute statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (field_1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i",
    $field 
);
$stmt->execute();

// Retrieve Autoincrement ID
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
```

Once you store the ID next you can execute a delete

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```